# Durable Subscriber is not receiving messages from Topic

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

I used the Subscriber SYSTEM.JMS.D.SUBSCRIBER.QUEUE and Client ID as setClientID("USER1") and used *topicSubscriber = topicSession.createDurableSubscriber(topic,"SUB1");*

The *topicSubscriber* is created and while trying to receive using this *topicSubscriber.receive();* , it is not receiving the messages from topic , but there are messages in topic.

Can any one say why its not receiving messages and whether i need to chek any queue configurations.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

---

I already had topicConnection.Start() in my coding , also i checked in TopicSession there is no Start() Method.

The same code with Non durable subscriber method *topicSession.createSubscriber(topic);* is working  , but for durable it is not working.

Thanks

---

Sorry, yes I meant topicConnection.Start().  It was worth a check.

---

I got the answer for durable subscriber not working ,
 My queue depth has reached the max queue depth , so the subscriber is not able to subscribe the message.

Eg . my max queue depth for queue SYSTEM.JMS.D.SUBSCRIBER.QUEUE is set to 100 , and if we check our current queue depth and if it reaches 100 the subscriber will not work.

As an alternative way iam trying to create with Temporary Topic , here iam getting an error while creating the durable subscriber *topicSession.createDurableSubscriber(topic,"SUB1");*

> JMS Exception :: javax.jms.InvalidDestinationException: MQJMS0003:
>   Destination not understood or no longer valid

Can anyone help to solve this error.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you call topicSession.start()? That is a common step missed in JMS applications. No messages will be delivered until the session is started.

Comment: Please do not post answers as followup to your question, edit your question instead. SO is not a forum, it's a Q&A engine. Questions up top, answers below (sorted by votes).

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to be how you are using `SYSTEM.JMS.D.SUBSCRIBER.QUEUE`.  You appear to be directing messages and subscribers to this queue as the destination for a durable subscription.  IBM MQ uses that queue to *manage* durable subscriptions.

As a general rule, queues whose names begin with `SYSTEM` are for internal system use by MQ.  Some of them, such as `SYSTEM.ADMIN.*.EVENT` are OK to get messages from but you would not use these as a subscription destination for unrelated messages either.

Many tutorials use `SYSTEM.DEFAULT.LOCAL.QUEUE` as a destination for messages but this is only because the queue is known to exist on all versions of MQ and MQ uses only the *definition* of the queue and never the *content* of that queue.  It is easier for the tutorial writer (and IBM is just as guilty here) to point at `SYSTEM.DEFAULT.LOCAL.QUEUE` then to walk the student through the need for and means to create their own queue.  So although best practices suggest it should not be an exception to the "do not use `SYSTEM` objects" rule, common usage makes `SYSTEM.DEFAULT.LOCAL.QUEUE` the de facto exception.

The other exceptions are, of course, the command queues for MQ, MFT and IIB.  These are also names `SYSTEM.*` but are designed for users to communicate with the software listening on the queue.

Note that all the exceptions "do not use `SYSTEM` objects" rule are interfaces between applications and MQ system resources.  The event queues are MQ sending information to the user.  The command queues are the user sending information to the system components.  A subscription is neither of these categories.  A destination for a subscription is considered an application-owned object, even when the system manages it on behalf of the subscriber.

When you want a durable subscription, either let the system assign a permanent queue and use that, or else pre-define a queue (that is not named `SYSTEM.*`) and use that.  Whatever else you do, please do NOT try to hijack MQ's internal system queues for application-level purposes.